# $(this).attr('id') gives blank values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I have a link as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php $res['id'];?>" class='bid_accept'>Accept</a>
```

I need to pass the value of `id` to another page using Framework7 as follows:

```
$$('.bid_accept').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var value = $(this).attr('id');
var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(value);
myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Custom Title', 
function (jsonstring) {
myApp.alert('Your name is "' + value + '". You clicked Ok button');
   },
function () {
myApp.alert('You clicked Cancel button');
   }
  );
});
```

I receive alerts as:

> Your name is **""**. You clicked Ok button

I also tried:

```
var value = this.id;
```

Why am I not getting the `id` value?

Comment: Because your id attibute is empty :)

You are missing the `echo` statement in `id="<?php $res['id'];?>"`

Comment: @php-dev yes, I tried that previously. I get:
Your name is "[object Object]". You clicked Ok button. But i have used JSON.stringify ???

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP, so we can see what the ID is, and recreate the issue in the snippet. Also, what's with the double dollar sign in `$$('.bid_accept')`?

Comment: I think so your attribute is empty.

Comment: The id is a dynamic value. The $$ sign is Framework7 specific.

Comment: I am getting the id fine in php. But it is not passed to jQuery as id.

Comment: I messed the code copying it here. It is now working perfectly fine. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: `myApp.alert('Your name is "' + value + '". You clicked Ok button');` has to be `myApp.alert('Your name is "' + jsonstring + '". You clicked Ok button');`

Comment: Inspect that element and see whether Id is present or not ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `JSON.stringfy(value)` it means you are setting that ID out of a JSON value, i do not know if i am write but the ID attribute takes a 1 word name and `JSON.stringfy()` produces multiple words separated by spaces. Let alone i think IDs have a specific number of characters so you might be intializing a very long name.
Not really sure what you want to achieve but HTML allows you to add attributes of your own and read them in JQuery like:

```
<a href="#" myAttr="<?php $res['id'];?>" class='bid_accept'>Accept</a>
```

such that when you click your code will be like:

```
$$('.bid_accept').on('click', function (e) {
var value = $(this).attr('myAttr');
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line has error

```
<a href="#" id="<?php $res['id'];?>" class='bid_accept'>Accept</a>
```

change it to

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $res['id'];?>" class='bid_accept'>Accept</a>
```

And in jquery part instead of $ you have to use $$.

```
var value = $$(this).attr('id'); // check $$ sign
```